# SQL Server 2012 can't select UDT for column in table designer

Tags: sql-server-2012, user-defined-types

In a SQL Server 2012 database, I am trying to create a User-Defined Data Type that multiple tables will use.

I created the data types, but then when I try to modify the existing tables (design view) I am unable to select the UDT I just created. I keep getting an error message 'Invalid data type.' I can't select it for a new column or new table, either.

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating a table via CREATE TABLE script, and found I was able to use the UDT, despite intellisense telling me it wasn't a recognized type.

When I tried opening the table in designer mode, I finally got the information I needed from SQL.

```
Table 'Tag' could not be loaded.

The table being loaded into memory has a user-defined data type 
('DM_DESC_100') that is not recognized. 
Close all of your open database diagram and table designer windows.
The new data type will be recognized when you re-open the diagram or
table designer.
```

Sure enough, when I did that, suddenly I could select my UDT in the table designer.